Eigenvalues of Hecke operators for Siegel eigenforms are algebraic
Cross-posted to MO
Let $F$ be a Siegel modular form for $\text{Sp}_4(\mathbb{Z})$ of genus two. Let it also be an eigenform for all the Hecke operators $T_n$, $n\geq1$ (genus two).
Are the eigenvalues corresponding to these Hecke operators algebraic?
I know that they are real owing to the fact that the Hecke operators are self adjoint. I'm aware of this analogous question in the genus 1 case regarding elliptic modular form, where the heart of the proof is the fact that we can find a basis with integer Fourier coefficients. In the genus two case, I know that (read in text) the Fourier coefficients are algebraic, but we do not have nice relation (as in genus 1 case) between them and the Hecke eigenvalues.
Any help, reference or related information?

I don’t really understand the story beyond $g>1$, but doesn’t the same argument applies – eigenforms correspond of systems of eigenvalues of Hecke operators act on a certain finitely generated abelian group (for $g=1$, the singular homology of modular curves).
